# resetting http_proxy in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, proxy

I am using **ubuntu 12.04**
whenever i am using sudo apt-get update in terminal or downloading anything from software manager it is showing me `can't resolve "proxy.iiith.ac.in` " now i don't want to use proxy.

So,
i tried following things.

- changed from system setting -> ntework ->made proxy none->apply system wide
- i changed /etc/apt/apt.conf.d file..

  ```
  Acquire::http::proxy "";
  Acquire::https::proxy "";
  Acquire::ftp::proxy "";
  Acquire::socks::proxy "";
  ```

but still its is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three things,

> 1) There are some lines added to `environment` file in `etc` so delete these lines like

```
acquire http_proxy = "proxy.xyz.ac.in"

acquire https_proxy = "proxy.xyz.ac.in"

acquire ftp_proxy = "proxy.xyz.ac.in"

acquire socks_proxy = "proxy.xyz.ac.in"
```

> 2) Similarly in `apt.conf` in`etc/apt` file same lines need to be *deleted* if you are not using any proxy.
>
> 3) And then **in terminal** execute following commands

```
unset http_proxy

unset https_proxy

unset ftp_proxy

unset socks_proxy
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the command:

```
 unset http_proxy
```

Comment: echo $http_proxy
it will give you somehting (your curent proxy settings) 
and unset http_proxy and then do echo $http_proxy it will return blank